# HTML email generation that supports all mail services

Tags: php, html-email

Is there any PHP script that can generate email templates that will support all email clients such as Yahoo,Gmail,Outlook,Hotmail etc.,? For example, it seems to be like inline styles are accepted in all mail services. So is there any way to generate inline styles for all the elements provided inside the `<style>...</style>` tag or something like that? I can't use any online services, since i have 1000 of email templates and which is increasing day by day. So any suggestion or ideas for this will be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found some great scripts for this around the web. But all are having lot of issues with them. And the following libray is almost satisfy my needs except that it is not supporting pseudo selectors. So i decided to avoid them in my CSS for email templates just for now.

And here is it,

https://github.com/tijsverkoyen/CssToInlineStyles

It is just converting all the styles into inline CSS which is working in almost all email clients.

Answer (score 0):

Pommo would be very good for what you want!

Main projet: http://pommo.org/Main_Page
Screen: http://www.flickr.com/photos/26392873@N00/sets/72157594430337337/show/
Download: https://sourceforge.net/projects/pommo/files/

I use it for several years, it works perfectly fine

Comment: I needed a PHP script to achieve this which i can run from my server itself...